# What are the reference counts of objects A and B after assigning B=A?

Tags: objective-c, reference-counting, retaincount

What is the reference count of `A` and `B` after assigning `B=A` in this code?

```
Class1 *A=[[Class1 alloc] init];
Class1 *B=[[Class1 alloc] init];

[A retain];
NSMutableArray *tempArray= [NSMutableArray alloc]init];
[tempArray addobject:A];
B=A;
```

Comment: What do you mean by step 5? Can you be more specific?

Comment: hi now i make it more specific

Comment: Can you please change the title too?

Comment: What is reference count for you?

Comment: Why do you have the `automatic-ref-counting` tag? If you can say `retain`, you are _not_ using automatic ref counting.

Answer (score 0):

Depends whether you use ARC, but since you have a `retain` in your code, I assume you don't use ARC.

```
Class1 *A=[[Class1 alloc] init];
```

A:1

```
Class1 *B=[[Class1 alloc] init];
```

A:1, B:1

```
[A retain];
```

A:2, B:1

```
NSMutableArray *tempArray= [NSMutableArray alloc]init];
```

A:2, B:1

```
[tempArray addobject:A];
```

A:3, B:1

**UPDATE**

```
B=A;
```

A:3, B:3 **BUT** the original B still exists with B':1

Comment: how after assigning B , B=2 and A=0, because behave same as weak

Comment: I don't really understand your question, but I am talking about the 'original' objects that were created. of course when you asign B=A the retain counter of A is the same as B BUT the original B still has a retain count of 1!

Answer (score 0):

This question seems to arise from a lack of distinction between the *objects* and the *pointers* to those objects. After your code has run, the *objects pointed to* by `A` and `B` have the same reference count value, because **they are the same object**. The assignment operation does not change the count of the object, and the pointers have no retain count. Only the objects do.

Objects are often talked about as if they are the same as their pointers -- "Pass object `A` into the method" -- because a) for the most part there's no relevant difference, and b) they can only be accessed via a pointer. This is one of the times that there's a relevant difference.

(After the assignment, the object that `B` originally pointed to has been leaked: it has a positive retain count but no pointers to it.)